# How set shadow navigationBar With UIView

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

how remove line That Arrows It points to

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please edit your post to provide a specific question, and explain what you have tried (including code if applicable).

Comment: if i understood correctly.you trying to add a shadow under your navigationBar is it?